# Vaadin button css background isn't working

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I am using Vaadin version 14.7.3.

I have a button

```
Button reminder_settings = new Button("Reminder settings", e->menuClick("Reminder settings"));
reminder_settings.setClassName("headliner");
```

and I have my css

```
@CssImport("./mainstyle.css")
```

The file has this

```
.headline {
font-weight: bold;
}
.headliner {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now, if I set the className to headline (without the r) my button is bold. But not when it has the className = headliner.

I also cannot add a background-color or anything similar.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a cheat-sheet for styling components?

Comment: Styling webcomponents is a bit harder than normal HTML tags. Please read https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/styling-components

Comment: Sounds like you might have problems with CSS Specificity, and while your style rule does get applied, some other style rule overrides it. If you inspect the applied styles in a browser, you might see your rule for `font-weight` crossed out, and some other rule as active. Adding `!important` to your rule might help. See e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Now, if I set the className to headline (without the r) my button is bold. But not when it has the className = headliner.

That sounds like there is something wrong with your CSS, some incorrect character perhaps, or some other typing error. Nothing else should make a difference between using a different class name.

> I also cannot add a background-color or anything similar.

Can you show what you tried to do? I assume you used the same classname(s) as before, and tried adding `background-color` there. That should work as well, as long as the CSS is in the same style scope as the button your are styling. Note, that some buttons might be inside shadow roots, and therefore global CSS selectors won't match them.

Comment: That is the while css file for that project. If I add background color. It would be like so: .headliner {
font-weight: bold; background-color: red;
} The file is in the node folder. What could I test to know if my file is incorrect? It does add the bold-font for my other headlines, but does nothing else for anything else if I try something else. Only headline = bold.

Comment: You could try `body { background: red !important; }` to know if the style sheet is being applied on the page.

Comment: Also, in case you haven’t seen the documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/importing-style-sheets